# VK Andoird SDK отправить документ на стену

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь из своего приложения расшарить на свою стену документ (гиф анимацию), используя этот код:

```
VKApiDocs docs = new VKApiDocs();
  VKRequest uploadWallServerRequest = docs.uploadWallDocRequest(file);
  uploadWallServerRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
      super.onComplete(response);
    }
  });
```

Насколько я понимаю, после исполнения этого кода (onComplete(VkResponse) происходит, запрос успешен) на стене моего профиля должна появться эта гиф-анимация. Но она появляется лишь в списке моих документов, на стене её нет.

Как сделать так, чтобы документ коазался на стене?

Answer (score 1):

Так, судя по всему не получится сделать.
Нужно после выполнения метода https://vk.com/dev/docs.save делать метод:

https://vk.com/dev/wall.post

Либо делать связку методов: docs.get (получить данные документа) + wall.post (прикреплять к записи документ).

Comment: Никак нет, метод docs.uploadWallDocRequest уже инкапсулирует в себе запросы 1) на получение url сервера для загрузки 2) загрузки документа на сервер 3) сохранение документа docs.save

Comment: Да это ясно, как день. Я имел ввиду то, что для того, чтобы запостить на стену документ - нужно вручную писать все методы. Все 4.

Comment: Не знаю что за 4-ый метод, их всего три, судя по документации. Какая разница между кодом, написанным вручную и тем, что инкапсулирован в методе, который я использую в вопросе?

Comment: Вы не туда смотрите. Вы используете комплекс из 3 методов из официального SDK.  А я предлагаю не использовать его, а написать отдельно 4 метода (3, которые из SDK + wall.post). Либо альтернативный способ, если вы хотите загрузить документ на стену. Ваш код загружает документ в ваши документы (в вк). Тогда просто выполните в приложении дальше метод wall.post, добавив к нему ID документа, который вы загрузили.